# Query updates in phpmyadmin but shows wrong query in website

Tags: mysql, sql

We have a project regarding showing the content of our database in a website after update. The updating part doesn't have a problem but showing the table have. Please do help. Here is the screen shot:

This is the screen shot of the query in the website:
[image: This is the screen shot of the query in the website:]
This is the screenshot of the database where in there's a problem
[image: This is the screenshot of the database where in there's a problem]

As you can see, The Paid and the CardTypeID columns are not getting the right data from the database. It only shows same data from all records.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT t.TransID, t.Date, m.MemID, m.FName, m.LName, m.Contact, c.CardTypeID,         m.CardNum, t.Amount, c.Paid, m.ExpiryDate FROM transaction t, members m, card c WHERE m.MemID = t.MemID GROUP BY T.MemID ORDER BY T.TransID DESC
```

Thanks for the help.

** Here are the other tables:

Members Table:

[image: Members Table Structure]

Transaction Table:

[image: Transaction Table Structure]

Card Table:

[image: Card Table Structure]

All of the data inside of them are the same specially the Member IDs.

Comment: Why did you remove the screen shots...

Comment: Please add how your table reference to another.

Comment: Sorry. I only fixed it. Here are the screen shots again. Edited it.

Comment: please check the database you have selected is the right one or not or may be same with the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not joined the Card C table properly... you need

```
SELECT t.transid, 
       t.date, 
       m.memid, 
       m.fname, 
       m.lname, 
       m.contact, 
       c.cardtypeid, 
       m.cardnum, 
       t.amount, 
       c.paid, 
       m.expirydate 
FROM   TRANSACTION t, 
       members m, 
       card c 
WHERE  m.memid = t.memid 
and c.transid = t.transid  //(if this field exists in both tables)
GROUP  BY T.memid 
ORDER  BY T.transid DESC
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. I thought the member id in the card table already connected them.

Answer (score 0):

Your join doesn't specify a criteria for the card table. So every row of the other two tables will be joined with every row of the card table.